# Shell script to display IP

Tags: scripts

How can I create a shell script which receives a vector argument like

./script.sh google.com,yahoo.com

and display ip for each domain

like google.com 100.23.123.13

---

EDIT:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while [ "$1" ]; 
do
host $1 | grep address | head -1
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for domain in $@; do
    host $domain | grep "has address" | awk '{print $1"\t"$4}'
done
```

Usage: `./script www.domain1.com domain2.com ...`

For example:

```
$ ./script.sh www.google.com yahoo.com www.askubuntu.com google.ro
www.google.com  173.194.40.81
www.google.com  173.194.40.84
www.google.com  173.194.40.82
www.google.com  173.194.40.83
www.google.com  173.194.40.80
yahoo.com   98.138.253.109
yahoo.com   206.190.36.45
yahoo.com   98.139.183.24
askubuntu.com   198.252.206.24
google.ro   173.194.35.31
google.ro   173.194.35.23
google.ro   173.194.35.24
```

Comment: I've edit my question. Please let me know what do you think.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform multiple-query lookups directly using the `dig` command e.g.

```
dig google.com yahoo.com
```

or for less verbose output

```
dig +noall +answer google.com yahoo.com
```

or to output just the IPs

```
dig +short google.com yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that this way.

Open a Terminal

```
$ gedit get_domain_ip.sh &
```

Add the following lines into the file and Save.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter domain name : " DOMAIN_INPUT

host $DOMAIN_INPUT

#END
```

Flag the script as executable

```
$ chmod +x get_domain_ip.sh
```

Testing

```
neo@neo-H87H3-M:~$ ./get_ip.sh

Enter domain name : google.com    
google.com has address 173.194.72.102    
google.com has address 173.194.72.101    
google.com has address 173.194.72.100    
google.com has address 173.194.72.139    
google.com has address 173.194.72.138    
google.com has address 173.194.72.113    
google.com has IPv6 address 2404:6800:4008:c00::8a    
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.    
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.    
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.    
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.    
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.

neo@neo-H87H3-M:~$
```

Comment: for multiple domains ? how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

For single domain input>>

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#get IP
host $1 | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1,"\t",$4}'
```

For multiple domain input>>

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#get IP
for url in $@; do
    host $url | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1,"\t",$4}'
done
```